# How get data stored in vars from a js file in python

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a js file that I need to get data out of but I am not sure how to get the data out in the way I want. I would like it to be readable and subscriptable like a python dict(like dict["key/value"]).

just opening the file returns an <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> but that doesn't seem to be what I want.

Then reading that returns a more usable <class 'str'> that I could use regex on but that seems unnecessary, I feel like there is a better way to do this.

```
with open(r'C:file.js') as dataFile:

   #returns <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
   print(type(dataFile))
   
   #returns <class 'str'>
   print(type(dataFile.read()))
```

I have tried looking into the modules (json) and (json5) but I am not sure if they get me what I need either.

for clarity I want to get the "county_info" data out of this(https://ce.naco.org/app/data/general.js) site(which I have saved as a js file)

Comment: could you post that JS here - or at least enough to help you? Seems the link does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The county_info is the first object in there.  So, just search for the delimiters"

```
import json

data = open('x.js').read()
i = data.find('{' )
j = data.find('}', i)
data = json.loads(data[i:j+1])
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating an example file, but I'm not too sure if this is what you had in mind.

https://replit.com/@hunter-macias/get-js-data#main.py

you can use .readlines() instead of read() to get all of your data as a list and then you just have to clean up your data based on how you formatted it